# How to modify AndroidManifest.xml in a Meteor 1.5 Cordova App?

Tags: cordova, meteor, android-manifest

I try to register my App into the sharing feature of android and I found that I have to modify the manifest.

I did:

```
App.appendToConfig(`
 <universal-links>
   <host name="com.toto.app" />
 </universal-links>
 <platform name="android">
   <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application/activity">
           <intent-filter>               
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <data android:mimeType="*/*" />                
           </intent-filter>    
   </config-file>
 </platform>
`);
```

The new lines appear in the config.xml but the intent-filter does not appear in the manifest and the app is not generated.

here is the error message

```
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
   Type Control-C twice to stop.

=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

   While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
   Error: Command failed: C:\dev\https://youtu.be/toto\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\cordova\run --device --device
   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   C:\dev\toto\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml:60: AAPT: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

   C:\dev\toto\.meteor\local\cordova-build\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\xml\config.xml:60: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the attribute `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` on every element that references the android namespace. In your case, that means:

```
App.appendToConfig(`
 <universal-links>
   <host name="com.toto.app" />
 </universal-links>
 <platform name="android">
   <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application/activity">
           <intent-filter>               
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
               <data android:mimeType="*/*" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />                
           </intent-filter>    
   </config-file>
 </platform>
`);
```

Comment: cordova-custom-config: Error updating config for platform 'android': Cannot use absolute path on element

Comment: Replacing /manifest by . resolves this issue, but all of this has strictly no impact.  In other words, I share a pic from the gallery app, but my app appears nowhere in the list of apps to be shared to.

Comment: btw, I was trying to follow https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/101/how-to-list-your-cordova-app-in-open-with-menu-in-android-and-handle-the-intent-event  .... with no success so far.

Comment: @Marc my answer was in response to the error message; the change I suggested was adding the `xmlns:android` attribute to all the elements that contain any other `android:*` attributes. This fixes the specific problem you were having. As for the new problem, I don't know the answer; but would suggest a new question.